Is set of integers closed under the operation of subtraction?
I was working on a problem, but my solution did not pass the time limit test.
Problem

Let's say a set of integers is closed under the operation of
subtraction if for two distinct elements of this set a and b, at least
one of the values a-b and b-a is also an element of this set.
You are given a set of integers. You need to determine whether it is
closed under the operation of subtraction or not.
Input: The first line contains a natural number n (2 ≤ n ≤ 5✕10⁵) -
the number of integers in the given set. The second line contains the
integers |aᵢ| ≤ 10⁹ - the elements of the set.
Output: Print "YES" if the given set is closed under the operation of
subtraction, otherwise print "NO".

Examples:
5
-4 -2 -6 -10 -8
YES

4
5 4 0 2
NO

3
1 2 3
YES

Code
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  long long n;
  std::cin >> n;

  std::vector<long long> vec(n);
  std::unordered_set<long long> elements;

  for (long long i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    std::cin >> vec[i];
    elements.insert(vec[i]);
  }

  for (long long i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (long long j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
      long long diff1 = vec[i] - vec[j];
      long long diff2 = vec[j] - vec[i];

      if (elements.find(diff1) == elements.end() && elements.find(diff2) == elements.end()) {
        std::cout << "NO" << std::endl;
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }

  std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

The current implementation has a time complexity of O(n²). Are there any techniques or data structures that could help optimize this further?

Why do you feel you need both the vector and the set?

@Chris, I can't apply the input operator to a set, so I use a vector and a set, providing O(1) complexity for finding elements.

@greybeard, A set of integers is closed under subtraction if for any two distinct elements
For the set {1, 2, 3}:
1 - 2 = -1 (not in the set), but 2 - 1 = 1 (in the set),
1 - 3 = -2 (not in the set), but 3 - 1 = 2 (in the set),
2 - 3 = -1 (not in the set), but 3 - 2 = 1 (in the set).
If at least one of these results is in the set for every pair, the set is closed. Otherwise, it's not.

Is this pulled from a site like Leetcode (suggested by the time limit), where there might be a discussion about ideal algorithms?

In view of a comment at indi's answer it might be helpful to clarify if the integers may contain duplicate elements or not. Probably not as it is called a “set.”

@TobySpeight: Re your edit: Is there a special reason to avoid MathJax/LaTeX? I personally find $10^5 $ to be better legible than 10⁵.

@Martin: I find 10⁵ more readable than \$10^5\$.  But that's perhaps because I don't do much LaTeX these days.

With the restriction on input that there are no duplicate values, I think this can be done in O(n) time and O(1) space. Now I'm really curious where this came from.

There are two steps to efficiently solving a problem in code:

Understand the problem thoroughly to find the most efficient theoretical solution.
Implement the solution effectively in code.

Most beginners skip the first step. When they get a problem, without even thinking about it for even ten seconds, they immediately start banging out code. Naturally, what tends to happen is they end up coding a brute force solution, which is almost always sub-optimal.
@JustinChang has more or less done the first step completely.⁕ As for the second step… so far, at the time of writing, no one has really stepped up.
⁕ (I assume. It’s late, I’m exhausted, and I’ve had a few, so I am really not up to doing a deep dive on the theoretical aspect of the problem. I’m just going to assume @JustinChang has got it licked.)
Let’s take a quick scan of the coded solutions we have so far, and take note of some obvious problems.
In the original code in the question, there is a vector… and a hashed set. Every single input number is read into the vector… and then again into the hashed set. As @Chris asked in the comments: “why both?” The answer given is that the vector is needed because one can’t input directly into a set… which is true… buuuut:
// Instead of:
auto vector   = std::vector<long long>{};
auto elements = std::unordered_set<long long>{};

for (long long i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    std::cin >> vector[i];
    elements.insert(vector[i]);
}

// Why not:
auto elements = std::unordered_set<long long>{};

for (long long i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    auto number = 0LL;
    std::cin >> number;
    elements.insert(number);
}

With just a moment’s consideration, we completely removed a vector that is potentially megabytes in size… and in the same move, potentially massively shrunk the problem down, because if we only iterate through the set, we won’t be dealing with duplicates.
So, we should just use a hashed set and not a vector right? Put a pin in that. We’ll get back to it.
Let’s now take a look at the solution @JustinChang offers. Astoundingly, this is even worse. It reads the entire input data set into a vector… and then copies most of that into ANOTHER vector… AND THEN (effectively) COPIES IT AGAIN via transformation into a massive bit set.
Again, let’s just stop for a second and think about what we’re actually doing. All we want to do is take out all the zeroes. There is no need to create a whole second vector for that. Just do: std::erase(v, 0);.
And if the objection is that we can’t just erase the zeroes because the vector is a const&… I’m reminded of a classic bad joke about a man who goes to the doctor and complains, “Doctor, my arm hurts when I do this thing,” and then the doctor solves his problem by saying: “well, then, don’t do that.” You can’t change the vector because it’s const? Well, then, don’t do that. Take it by value (and move), or as a forwarding reference (and move). Or, hell, go ahead and take it as const&, but then just use a filter view. You have options. Don’t screw your program’s efficiency over due to some religious devotion to the idea that arguments must be passed by const&.
But even worse is the solution from @Chris, which—again—reads the entire input data set into a vector… copies most of that into another vector… and then straight-up copies it all again into a hashed set!
Let’s just stop for a moment, and think about what we’re coding. There are basically two strategies here:

The original code and the solution by @Chris both want the data in a hashed set (again, put a pin in that; we’ll get back to it). At no point, ever, is the entire, raw data set needed.
The solution by @JustinChang doesn’t use a set (hashed or otherwise), but when we look at what it actually does, it doesn’t need the entire data set either. It ultimately just needs to be able to find the minimum value, and then go over every unique value for its final test.†

† (There is something fishy about the logic around zero being completely superfluous. It seems to me that the set “0, 5, 5” is closed, but the set “5, 5” is not. But whatever, I said I was just going to accept their logic as-is, so I will.)
Note that neither strategy requires holding on to the entire input data set.
Both the original code and @Chris solution just want the data in a hashed set, so we could just do:
auto main() -> int
{
    // Don't really need this; could just ignore the first line.
    auto n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;

    auto elements = std::unordered_set{
        std::istream_iterator<std::int_fast32_t>{std::cin},
        std::istream_iterator<std::int_fast32_t>{}
    };

    // Now just do either the looping test in the original question
    // solution, or in the @Chris solution.
}

Yup. That’s the whole program. Easy peasy. Not the most efficient, but, again, keep that pin in there for now.
You could improve this with C++23:
auto main() -> int
{
    auto n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;

    auto elements = std::views::istream<std::int_fast32_t>{std::cin}
        | std::views::take(n)
        | std::ranges::to<std::unordered_set>()
    ;

    // Again, just do either the looping test in the original question
    // solution, or in the @Chris solution.
}

If, as per the @JustinChang solution, you want the data in a vector with the zeroes removed, then you could do:
auto main() -> int
{
    auto n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;

    auto v = std::views::istream<std::int_fast32_t>{std::cin}
        | std::views::take(n)
        | std::views::filter([](auto i) { return i != 0; })
        | std::ranges::to<std::vector>()
    ;

    // ...
}

This is not the most efficient solution, because it doesn’t pre-allocate the vector, but that is trivial to fix. I won’t bother because we have bigger fish to fry here.
Let’s go back to all the solutions that use a hashed set. Why are we doing that? Because it’s the “obvious” thing to do? Because we should always use hashed sets rather than plain old un-hashed sets because hashed set are always better?
Again, let’s stop and think about the problem for a few seconds.
What are we putting in this hashed set? Integers, non? And, what is the hash of an integer?
Well, what do you think?
A hashed set is considerably more complicated and expensive than a plain set, but usually that extra cost is worth it because the hashing reduces the comparison cost enormously. Like, for example, comparing hashes of strings can be multiple orders of magnitude faster than comparing the strings directly.
But given that the hash of an integer is the same freakin’ integer (or, even if not, could be), there is literally zero benefit to comparing hashes of integers over just straight-up comparing the freakin’ integer. And all the substantial costs of maintaining the hash table, the buckets etc.… now all that is just dead weight. Zero benefits. All costs.
So, I ask again: why are we using hashed sets? Hm?
Let’s pause here and revisit the original code, with all the things we’ve considered so far. It might look like this:
auto main() -> int
{
    auto n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;

    auto elements = std::set<std::int_fast32_t>{};
    for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        auto number = std::int_fast32_t{};
        std::cin >> number;
        elements.insert(number);
    }

    auto const end = std::ranges::end(elements);
    for (auto i = std::ranges::begin(elements); i != end; ++i)
    {
        for (auto j = std::ranges::begin(elements); j != i; ++j)
        {
            auto const diff1 = *i - *j;
            auto const diff2 = *j - *i;

            if (not elements.contains(diff1) and not elements.contains(diff2))
            {
                std::cout << "NO\n";
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "YES\n";
}

I wouldn’t call that optimized code at all, yet it might be efficient enough to pass the time limit.
One easy way to make the program faster is to have it bail early. If @JustinChang is correct that a set cannot be closed if it has both negative and positive values, we can add that test:
auto main() -> int
{
    auto n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;

    auto elements = std::set<std::int_fast32_t>{};
    auto seen_positive = false;
    auto seen_negative = false;
    for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        auto number = std::int_fast32_t{};
        std::cin >> number;

        if (number < 0)
            seen_negative = true;
        else if (number > 0)
            seen_positive = true;

        // It seems to me we might also need two more flags:
        // seen_zero and seen_duplicate, the latter of which would
        // be set if elements.contains(number). After reading all the
        // values in, either both should be true, or neither. But, like
        // I said, I'm not nitpicking the theory stuff.

        if (seen_negative and seen_positive)
        {
            std::cout << "NO\n";
            return 0;
        }

        elements.insert(std::abs(number)); // Do we need abs?
    }

    // ...
}

Another thing that might speed things up is to not use std::set (or std::unordered_set), but rather just use a sorted vector and binary searches. (C++23 actually has std::flat_set for that.)
By the way, one thing @JustinChang did that I strongly recommend you do too is use a function. Just dumping an entire program into main() is bad form, but especially so when it’s so obviously a self-contained algorithm. In this case, your program should look like:
template<std::ranges::input_range R>
requires std::integral<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>>
constexpr auto is_closed_under_subtraction(R&& r) -> bool
{
    // basically exactly the same code you have now in main()
}

auto main() -> int
{
    if (is_closed_under_subtraction(std::views::istream<std::int_fast32_t>(std::cin)))
        std::println("YES");
    else
        std::println("NO");
}

Or, if you really want to get fancy, you can even generalize the operation:
template<
    std::ranges::input_range R,
    std::invocable<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>, std::ranges::range_value_t<R>> Op
>
requires std::integral<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>>
constexpr auto is_closed_under_operation(R&& r, Op op) -> bool
{
    // basically exactly the same code you have now in main(),
    // except instead of "a - b" and "b - a", you do "op(a, b)" and
    // "op(b, a)".
}

auto main() -> int
{
    if (is_closed_under_operation(std::views::istream<std::int_fast32_t>(std::cin), std::minus{}))
        std::println("YES");
    else
        std::println("NO");
}

Anywho, if there’s a moral here, it is that you shouldn’t brainlessly barf up patterns in your code. Don’t pass arguments by const& just because “that’s what you do”. Don’t use hashed maps or sets just because “hashed stuff is faster”. And don’t throw in a vector just because you can’t stream-extract directly into a set. Think about what you’re using, and why. A lot of the time, the normally “perfect” solution… isn’t.

To clarify, my understanding is that 5,5 is not a set because it has duplicate elements. If duplicate elements are not allowed, 0 doesn't matter. If we allow duplicate elements, the theory would change to: (i) if 0 is not an element, any duplicate makes the set not closed and (ii) if 0 is an element, remove 0 and all duplicates before proceeding. +1 for some C++ features that I otherwise haven't encountered.

I am not sure if I understand your arguments about hashed/non-hashed sets correctly. The original code uses a std::unordered_set (hashed) set in order to determine quickly if a difference is present in the set. Search in an unordered_set has average constant-time complexity, whereas search in a std::set has logarithmic complexity. The fact that an integer is equal to its hash value does not affect that and seems irrelevant to me.

@MartinR the constant factors involved in hashing can easily be bigger that the largest possible logarithmic factor, because our sets are bounded in size. Strictly speaking any solution to this problem is constant-time complexity

You know, I considered putting in a section about big-O/complexity, basically saying that because so many people don’t really understand it, you’d be a better programmer if you just forgot about it completely and just always use std::vector. That applies here; I’d bet that reading all the data into a vector, sorting it, and then using binary searches would probably be much faster than std::set and std::unordered_set.

@MartinR What Caleth says is technically correct, but there’s a much simpler way to understand what’s going on. Just think about what a hash set does when you search for a value: 1) calculate the hash of the search value; 2) find that in the hash table; 3) use the hash table to find the stored value; and 4) compare the search value to the stored value. 1/2

Even if a hash set were magical and actually O(1) (it’s not; it’s O(1) on average), then if the hash is the same as the value, you should be able to drop steps 1, 3, and 4. So whatever “magic” is happening to make a hash lookup O(1)… we can just do that without the hashing, or the extra step of linking from the key in the hash table (the hash) to the value. Thus when the hash is the same as the value, we can always be faster than a hash table. 2/2

For posterity, indi's answer addresses version 10 of my solution. My revised approach uses more math to avoid the copying discussed above. I do like indi's boolean flags approach and incorporated it as all_positive = !seen_negative and all_negative = !seen_positive.

Zeros don't affect anything because sets don't allow duplicates. The set {5, 5} is just {5}. (The problem uses a highly nonstandard definition of "closed under subtraction", though - the standard definition allows picking the same element twice, and requires both a-b and b-a to be in the set. The only finite sets of integers closed under subtraction under the standard definition are {0} and {}.)

I am aware of the mathematical definition of “set”. I am, however, mystified that you recognize that the problem statement uses a non-standard definition of “closed”, but don’t consider the possibility that it is also using a non-standard definition of “set”. This is software engineering 101: if the problem statement doesn’t say X, you don’t assume X; you either ask for clarification, or code defensively. In this case, it is fairly trivial for most solutions to account for duplicates in a way that is either low-cost or easy to “fix” if it later becomes clear there are no duplicates.

… or, at the very least, make explicit that you are assuming something not explicit in the problem statement.

Adding / removing 0 from the set does not change whether it is closed. Therefore, you can discard zeroes from the input. For convenience, suppose there are n nonzero elements. When n = 0, the set is closed because we cannot apply subtraction.
When the set is nonempty, let the minimum integer be x_min and let the maximum integer be x_max. If x_min < 0 and x_max > 0, then the set is not closed. Proof:

x_max > 0 implies x_max - x_min > 0 - x_min implies |x_max - x_min| > |x_min|
x_min < 0 implies x_max - x_min > x_max - 0 implies |x_max - x_min| > |x_max|

Thus, a set is only closed if it does not mix positive and negative elements.
Note that multiplying all elements by a nonzero constant does not change whether or not a set is closed. If all elements are negative, multiply them by -1 for convenience.
We have now reduced the problem to checking whether a nonempty set of positive integers is closed. Without loss of generality, let x_min = x_1 < x_2 < ... < x_n. Let diff(i, j) = x_j - x_i. Note that diff(1, 2) < diff(1, 3) < ... < diff(1, n). There are n-1 such terms and they are all less than x_n. Thus, a set is not closed if any of the following are false:
diff(1, 2) = x_1
diff(1, 3) = x_2
...
diff(1, n) = x_(n-1)

With similar logic, a set is not closed if any of the following are false:
diff(1, 2) = x_1
diff(2, 3) = x_1
diff(3, 4) = x_1
...
diff(n-1, n) = x_1

Let's substitute back terms:
x_2 - x_1 = x_1
x_3 - x_2 = x_1
x_4 - x_3 = x_1
...
x_n - x_(n-1) = x_1

The solution x_i = i * x_min for i in [1, 2, ... , n] is necessary for a set to be closed.
This is sufficient because for j in [1, 2, ... , n] such that i < j, we get j - i is in [1, 2, ... , n]. Thus, x_j - x_i = j * x_min - i * x_min = (j - i) * x_min = x_(j - i).
Clarity Edit: A vector of n > 0 distinct positive integers with minimum x_min is a permutation of [x_min, 2 * x_min, ... , n * x_min] if and only if each element is (i) a multiple of x_min and (ii) at most n * x_min by Pigeonhole Principle. This fact replaces my initial approach, which used more memory through unordered_set.
Below is an implementation that isolates the reduced problem into a helper function.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// is a set of positive integers closed?
bool is_closed(const std::vector<long long> &v) {
    size_t n = v.size();

    if (n < 1) // cannot apply subtraction
        return true;

    long long x_min = *std::min_element(
        v.begin(), v.end());

    // does sort(v / x_min) give [1, 2, ... , n]?
    long long x_max = x_min * n;

    for (const auto &x : v)
        if (x % x_min != 0 || x > x_max)
            return false;

    return true;
}

int main() {
    size_t n_with_zeroes; // includes zeroes
    std::cin >> n_with_zeroes;

    bool all_pos = true;
    bool all_neg = true;

    // absolute value of all elements
    std::vector<long long> v_abs;
    v_abs.reserve(n_with_zeroes);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_with_zeroes; ++i)
    {
        long long x;
        std::cin >> x;

        if (x == 0) // discard zeroes from input
            continue;

        if (x < 0)
        {
            all_pos = false;
            v_abs.push_back(-x); // convenience
        }
        else
        {
            all_neg = false;
            v_abs.push_back(x);
        }
    }

    // all positive or all negative? not mixed
    if ((all_pos || all_neg) && is_closed(v_abs))
        std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "NO" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

Hope this helps! It should have O(n) worst-case time complexity (optimal) and O(n) worst-case total space complexity (optimal). It might be doable with less auxiliary space.
Duplicates?
If the input permits duplicates (i.e. not a mathematical set), we must add an additional check:

If the set contains 0, remove all duplicates and proceed normally.
If the set does not contain 0, any duplicate makes the set not closed.

This can be done with an unordered_set.
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>

// is a set of positive integers closed?
bool is_closed(const std::unordered_set<long long> &v) {
    // same implementation as above
}

int main() {
    size_t n_with_zeroes; // includes zeroes
    std::cin >> n_with_zeroes;

    bool all_pos = true;
    bool all_neg = true;
    bool has_zero = false;
    bool no_dups = true;

    // absolute value of all elements
    std::unordered_set<long long> v_abs;
    v_abs.reserve(n_with_zeroes);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_with_zeroes; ++i)
    {
        long long x;
        std::cin >> x;

        if (x == 0) // discard zeroes from input
        {
            has_zero = true;
            continue;
        }
        else if (x < 0)
        {
            all_pos = false;
            if (v_abs.find(-x) != v_abs.end())
                no_dups = false;
            v_abs.insert(-x); // convenience
        }
        else
        {
            all_neg = false;
            if (v_abs.find(x) != v_abs.end())
                no_dups = false;
            v_abs.insert(x);
        }
    }

    // all positive or all negative? not mixed
    if ((all_pos || all_neg) && (no_dups || has_zero) && is_closed(v_abs))
        std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "NO" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```


Seems like this is O(n log n): for (long long i = 0; i < n; ++i)         if (elements.find() ...   (assuming find() is O(log n))

I believe that access for std::unordered_set has average constant time complexity, but will revise to make the worst-case better.

std::endl seems unnecessary here, we're not throwing exceptions or anything that might make us care about when we flush the stream buffer.  A simple std::cout << "YES\n" or "NO\n" is simpler and more efficient.  (Platform-specific newline handling happens at a different level than this; std::endl is defined as equivalent to outputting '\n' and flushing the stream.)

It's not clear from the problem statement whether the input is a strict set or whether it's a multiset (in which case we need 0 to be a member if any value appears more than once).  I think your answer assumes strict set, but it's not hard to modify it to make the opposite assumption if that turns out to be the actual requirement.  Good work!

This latest version doesn't eliminate duplicates, so I think it would misidentify the input [1, 1, 3] as closed.

Fair points @TobySpeight and @SebastianRedl. I have added a brief version that handles duplicates with std::unordered_set, albeit with a performance tradeoff.

I use pypy for project Euler because I like less code and I think you can write the entire is_closed function as: def is_closed(v): return len(v) < 1 or not any(x % min(v) or x > min(v)*len(v) for x in v). You can decide if that's easier to read or not.

Very cool @qwr. The problem would be so elegant if they had specified "a set of unique positive integers" from the start. I was surprised that checking for zeroes / negatives / duplicates is "the hard part", at least in terms of lines written.

It's not a lot of lines in a functional language or python list comprehensions. All positive can be something like all(x > 0 for x in v). Duplicates can be done as len(set(v)) == len(v) which isn't too slow. Zeros is just 0 in v. I am pretty sure with modern C++ you can cut down on LOC a lot if you care about that kinda thing.

The professor I had for our competition programming mini-class was Danny Sleator. He wasn't ultra fast at banging out solutions but he used OCamL and his graph algorithms were concise. Personally I'm looking for a competition programming language that isn't as verbose as C++ but has more consistent speed than pypy.

unnecessary to call unordered_set::find(), since the information's available in second of the pair returned from insert().   no_dups &= v_abs.insert(x).second;

Offered as an addendum to Justin Chang's excellent answer, there are a number of opportunities to further streamline that code, particularly leveraging algorithm.
A conscious choice has been made to avoid anything newer than C++17 to maximize compatibility, not knowing the OP's build environment.
bool is_closed(const std::vector<long long> v_with_zero) {
    // make a copy removing zero
    std::vector<long long> v;
    std::copy_if(
        v_with_zero.cbegin(), v_with_zero.cend(), 
        std::back_inserter(v),
        [](const auto &x) { return x != 0; }
    );

    long long n = v.size();

    // can't compute minimum on empty set
    if (n < 1)
        return true;

    // count number of negatives
    long long n_negative = std::count_if(
        v.cbegin(), v.cend(),
        [](const auto &x) { return x < 0; }
    );

    // if at least one negative ...
    if (n_negative > 0)
    {
        // ... they must all be negative
        if (n_negative < n)
            return false;

        // make them all positive
        std::transform(
            v.begin(), v.end(),
            v.begin(),
            [](auto &x) { return x * -1; }
        );
    }

    std::unordered_set<long long> elements { v.cbegin(), v.cend() };

    long long x_min = *std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end());

    for (long long i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (elements.find(x_min * (i + 1)) == elements.end())
            return false;

    return true;
}


I’m not sure why one would choose to use old-fashioned algorithms instead of modern ranges algorithms. Indeed, a sprinkle of ranges could, for the vast majority of potential inputs, massively speed things up.

The problem seemed to have its basics in an online constructive programming site. I suspected the OP does not have control over the compiler or compilation options. C++17 seems reasonably safe, but newer features less so.

C++17 is two versions old. I am not aware of any coding sites that do not support it. Indeed, any coding site that doesn’t could hardly be considered a credible coding site. It’s long past time to be thinking of C++20 as “newer”.

@indi: Agreed for new code.  For some existing codebases, some devs prefer to not to change the build to newer C++ versions until they really want some new language feature, so having to write for old C++ versions is a thing that happens.  In this case, maybe this answer should be edited to mention that it's limiting itself to C++17 and at least mention in words how you'd do what it's doing with C++20 or C++23, or which part of another answer to look at if it's already covered.

@PeterCordes There is really no reason to explain the obvious.
